# How to tag friends on Facebook using python

Tags: python, facebook

I've been trying different approaches to publish a happy new year message to all my friends using a python script. Now that I know that publishing to someone's wall is no longer permitted, I'm trying to post to my wall with SELF privacy and add a tag of my friend, so only he/she can read it, and the same for each friend.

The "for" loop is already working. The problem is the tagging part.
The id are in unicode, and the interpreter states an error about ascii code when I try to post. I left that behind and tried to tag a single user, in order to make it work.

```
graph.put_object("me", "feed", privacy={'value': 'SELF'},message="Hello there @[1234567890]")
```

But that will post the whole string... If I leave the `@[1234567890]` out of the quotation marks " ", the interpreter states a syntax error.

I've been searching and there is nothing using `put_object` from facebook-sdk. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

you can define the message it self as a unicode string.

```
message = u'Hello there @[' + id + u']'
```

or you can convert the id to ascii

```
message = 'Hello there @[' + id.encode('ascii', errors='backslashreplace') + ']'
```

Comment: Thanks! Using the first approach I receive the following error...
"TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found"
If I enclose the id number between quotation marks, it does post the message, but it does not tag anyone...
The second approach I had to set id = "123456789", and it does post the message, but it does not tag anyone, it just says "Hello there @[123456789]" 
Any ideas?

Comment: I just tried posting the message with @ name and @ username which I got from graph.get_object("123456789"), and it does post the message, but it is not a tag... it post just a string, and the post don't let the friend let know that it was tagged.